Equivalent(?) way of defining tensor product
The most general definition of tensor product of vector spaces I've found is through universal property. However, if I understand correctly, it defines two objects at the same time: the tensor product space $ T $ and the tensor product map $ \tau : U \times V \to T $, which doesn't feel very straightforward for me to think of.
Then I came to the following seemingly alternate "definition":
Given vector space $ U, V $ over field $ \mathbb{F} $, the vector space $ T $ over field $ \mathbb{F} $ such that for any vector space $ Z $ over $ \mathbb{F} $,
$$ Hom(T,Z) \cong Bilin(U,V;Z) $$
is unique (up to an isomorphism), and is defined to be the tensor product space of $ U $ and $ V $;
(this is actually directly from the universal property if I understand correctly)
Then we need the tensor product map. Any bilinear map $ \tau: U \times V \to T\; $ s.t. $ \; span(im\;\tau)=T $ seems to be the same as the quotient space construction, but I'm not sure how to formally prove it. If they are indeed the same, $ T $ and $ \tau $ should then satisfy the universal property, and $ \tau $ is unique(by a difference of an isomorphism) as well. Another problem is that I wonder if this can be derived from universal property, so that the two statements are equvialent(unfortunately I'm not very familiar with the related techniques)
If the construction above is correct, is it generally a good practice to define / think of tensor product of vector spaces this way?

Your definition should  also include a specific isomorphism $F_Z:Hom(T,Z)\to Bilin(U,V;Z)$ for each $Z$, and these  $F_Z$'s should constitute a natural transformation, i.e., they should commute with the maps that  result from a map $Z\to Y$.  Then you can define the  bilinear map $\tau$ as $F_T(\text{id}_T)$.Your proposed  definition of $\tau$ doesn't determine it uniquely.

(1) The universal property is not a definition, as it does not guarantee that a tensor product exists. It's moreso a description of what a tensor product "should be". (2) If you think that $T$ is a tensor product, why don't you try proving that it satifies the universal property? If you have specific trouble/doubts in doing so, then you should add those to your question.

@NicholasTodoroff Thanks for the advice on (2), I've edited the question and hopefully it made my troubles clearer. About (1), perhaps the universal property is more like an "axiom", and other constructions/definitions can be seen as proves that such objects exist?

Yes, you can think of the universal property as a set of axioms and a construction $T$ as an actual model for those axioms. As such you cannot really derive a specific $T$ from the universal property. However, it does suggest something: if we set $Z = \mathbb F$ then we want $$T^* \cong \mathrm{Bilin}(U, V; \mathbb F)$$ so it stands to reason that we should try $$T = \mathrm{Bilin}(U, V; \mathbb F)^*,$$ i.e. the dual space of the space of bilinear forms on $U, V$. Now with this concrete $T$, you should try to prove the universal property.

A comment on language: as per @NicholasTodoroff's now about "definitions", you might want to call these "characterizations" instead.

I'm still not seeing why the universal property is not a definition. The existence should be proven, but how does it effect the definition itself?
Wikipedia and many other maths texts I found all uses universal property as "definition", which often come later with constructions to prove the existence, but they are not a part of the definition.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product#Definitions_and_constructions

I do not like the language Wikipedia uses at all. This sentence was particularly bad: "It follows that this is a (non-constructive) way to define the tensor product of two vector spaces." If I were forced to use the word "define" here, the language I would use is that the universal property is the definition of what a tensor product is, but it is not a definition the tensor product. I don't like this though.

There is an analogy with the difference between the axioms of a group and a particular group, but what confounds the situation here is that tensor products are unique-up-to-unique-isomorphism, whereas groups of course are not.


However, if I understand correctly, it defines two objects at the same time: the tensor product space $T$ and the tensor product map $τ:U×V→T$, which doesn't feel very straightforward for me to think of.

The universal property does not define $T$ nor $\tau$. This is like saying that the axioms of a group $G$ with multiplication $\mu$ define $G$ and $\mu$.
The map $\tau$ is also the very essence of a tensor product. If you have "just" a vector space $T$ then you might as well have nothing since "just" vector spaces are entirely classified by their dimension. Going back to the group analogy, $G$ is just a set, and sets are entirely classified by their cardinality; what really makes a group is the multiplication $\mu$ and the properties it satisfies.
A tensor product (not the tensor product) is most rigorously defined as a bilinear map $\tau$ on $U\times V$ which satisfies the universal property. Note that we don't really need to specify $T$ since $T = \mathrm{Im}(\tau)$. You could call $T$ the carrier space of the tensor product. There are infinitely many $\tau$ which are tensor products; once we choose one, it is standard to denote $\tau(u, v)$ as $u\otimes v$.

Given vector space $U,V$ over field $\mathbb F$, the vector space T over field F such that for any vector space $Z$ over $\mathbb F$,
$$Hom(T,Z)≅Bilin(U,V;Z)$$
is unique (up to an isomorphism), and is defined to be the tensor product space of $U$ and $V$.

This fails as a definition. First, you should say (and it is quite standard language) that "if it exists, it is unique up to isomorphism". (And for tensor products the statement is even stronger: they are unique up to unique isomorphism.) Second, like I said above and like Andreas Blas says in the comments, the essence of the tensor product is the map $\tau$ satisfying the universal property, or equivalently the maps $F_Z : Hom(T,Z)\cong Bilin(U,V;Z)$ which satisfy properties equivalent to the universal property. If you don't have these things, then the only thing this definition does is fix the dimension of $T$.

Then we need the tensor product map. Any bilinear map $τ:U×V→T$ s.t. $span(im\,τ)=T$ seems to be the same as the quotient space construction, but I'm not sure how to formally prove it.

You can't prove this because (1) your "definition" gives you nothing to work with, and so you can't prove anything; (2) the quotient construction is a quotient of the free vector space on $U\times V$, not some quotient of $U\times V$ itself; and (3) you haven't constructed anything. The quotient space construction actually gives you an object $T$; it isn't just a characterization. What is true is that when you construct $T$ as a quotient, the natural projection restricted to $U\times V$ is a bilinear map $U\times V \to T$ which satisfies the universal property.
To expand on (1), it is not enough the the maps $F_Z$ exists. They must also be compatible in the following way: for any linear $l : Z \to Z'$ and any linear $m : T \to Z$ we must have
$$
  l\circ F_Z(m) = F_{Z'}(l\circ m).
$$
Once we have this property, we can take $\tau = F_T(\mathrm{id}_T)$ and prove that this satisfies the universal property, but there is no way to prove that an arbitrary $\mu$ does so.

Let's make it clear what it is that you've actually done here. The condition $$Hom(T,Z)≅Bilin(U,V;Z)$$ for all $Z$ merely guarantees that $\dim(T) = \dim(U)\dim(V)$. So really we can just say that we have a bilinear map $\tau$ on $U\times V$ such that $\dim\mathrm{Im}(\tau) = \dim(U)\dim(V)$; and indeed, perhaps in some Platonic sense any such map is a tensor product, but you cannot prove it because you don't have enough structure to do so!

I'm aware that the quotient construction is a quotient of the free vector space on $ U \times V $. I think from the quotient space construction one should be able to derive that $ \otimes: U \times V \to U \otimes V $ satisfies $ span(im;\otimes)=U \otimes V $, but maybe not the other way around.

Following your arguments, the question is then "whether the universal property characterization could be stated so that $ T $ and $ \tau $ are separately characterized", as suggested by @JonathanZ, but that won't be necessary (though I'm still curious) since in that case I wouldn't have trouble accepting it as a characterization

@cloudri Yes, this is included in "the natural projection restricted to $U×V$ is a bilinear map $U×V→T$ which satisfies the universal property." I'm not sure what you mean by "the other way around."

I don't really understand what you want when you say you want $T$ and $\tau$ to be "separately characterized". $T$ is a vector space; so it is entirely characterized by dimension; so the best you can say to characterize it "separately" from $\tau$ is that $\dim(T)=\dim(U)\dim(V)$. Like I've been trying to say, $T$ "separately" is quite boring and useless, and the whole point and essence of a tensor product is really in the map $\tau$.

Since I was originally viewing the universal property as a definition, I was not comfortable with it "defining" both $ T $ and $ \tau $ at the same time, it felt weird to declare a map when the set into which it is mapping is not known. That's probably why I'm desperate to know what $ T $ is, because I'm not very sure if we can talk about a map without knowing what it is mapping into

@cloudri Maybe you understand already, but going back to the group analogy, that's like looking at the group axioms stated in terms of a set $G$ and map $\mu:G\times G\to G$, asking "what is $G$", and being uncomfortable that $G$ and $\mu$ are being "defined at the same time".

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
